# Are Shikadai and Yodo cousins?

Tags: boruto

I know this might seem like a idiotic question but it has been bothering me lately. Are Shikadai and Yodo cousins? I see a lot of fanart with them being shipped together,so i was just trying to clarify this.

Comment: While the question is on-topic and should be answerable, there are many reasons (or even, no reason) why someone is shipped with another...

Comment: Shipping in anime do not really have a defined set of rules of who can or cannot be shipped. Characters could be a brother and a sister and fans would still be shipping them...

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, I do not believe Yodo's parents have been official confirmed. So it cannot be confirmed or denied if Yodo and Shikadai are cousins.

However, Yodo does have slight resemblance to Temari as she was shown in the original Naruto series. Prior to Temari's and Shikimaru's official relationship, they were paired together as a fan-couple. With that, fans are likely pairing Yodo and Shikadai together similar to how Temari and Shikimaru were paired together.